# Where to put gtag tracking codes in Shopify store having Empire theme?

Tags: javascript, shopify, tracking

I need a hand. In the Empire theme of my Shopify store, I need to put corresponding tracking codes:

```js
//when a product is viewed in store
  gtag('event', 'view_item', {
    'send_to': ‘…..’,
    'value': …..,
    'items': [{
      'id': ‘…….’,
      'google_business_vertical': ‘…….’
    }]
  });
 
//when a product is added to cart
  gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
    'send_to': ‘…..’,
    'value': …..,
    'items': [{
      'id': ‘…….’,
      'google_business_vertical': ‘…….’
    }]
  });
 
 
//when a product is purchased
  gtag('event', 'purchase', {
    'send_to': ‘…..’,
    'value': …..,
    'items': [{
      'id': ‘…….’,
      'google_business_vertical': ‘…….’
    }]
  });
```

Can someone please, share step-by-step instructions how and where to put these codes exactly, in order to make them do the right thing?
Also, should I call any other script in  section, and which?
What additional things I need to do?
Where can I read more about these and similar things?

My question is **not** about Shopify! I am referring to the Empire theme itself. The upper codes need to be placed in the theme itself. Where exactly in the theme I need to put those codes to do trackings when a product is viewed in store, when a product is added to cart and when a product is purchased, as stated just above each piece of script.

Please, be as precise as you can.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding individual scripts, it would be better to go with Google Tag Manager option. Adding individual scripts would increase the load time of the website, for removing this issue Google has introduced the concept of Tag Manager.

You just need to add two codes in your theme.liquid file on the head as well as the body of the file. After that tag manager would setup. 
All you need to do is to sign in into Google Tag Manager after that create the properly, once the property is created you can add these two scripts in the theme.liquid file. After that on Google Tag Manager, you can create these events.
1)Please refer this screenshot for creating of Property https://prnt.sc/p16loj

2)Once the property is created, you can add the script from the second step, please refer this screenshot https://prnt.sc/p16n7o

3)You can select Analytics and setup event from here https://prnt.sc/p16owz

4)You can select the desired event from here 
https://prnt.sc/p16qam